# How to index bulk json file to elasticsearch in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a JSON file and I want to know how to index it to the elasticsearch in spring boot

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Spring Data Elasticsearch component and index the JSON using the [bulk API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/DocumentOperations.html#bulkIndex-java.util.List-org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.BulkOptions-java.lang.Class-).

You have to convert the JSON into a relevant Java Object using libraries like [GSon](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html).

It uses the Elasticsearch High-level REST Client and the [_bulk](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html) underlying.